# How to mix php in css inside a php file?

Tags: php, css

Please help, I have a gradient css style inside a php file:

```
<?php
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.styleku-slidercontainer {
   background: #0a4999; /* Old browsers */
   /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
   background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0a4999 0%, #22b6f4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0a4999), color-stop(100%,#22b6f4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #0a4999 0%,#22b6f4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #0a4999 0%,#22b6f4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #0a4999 0%,#22b6f4 100%); /* IE10+ */
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #0a4999 0%,#22b6f4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0a4999', endColorstr='#22b6f4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */}
```

I want to change the color 1 (`#0a4999`) and color 2 (`#22b6f4`) dynamically, so I create some php codes:

```
.styleku-slidercontainer {
        /*background-color: #fff;*/

        background: <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?>; /* Old browsers */
        /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
        background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIwJSIgeTI9IjEwMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzBhNDk5OSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyMmI2ZjQiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);

        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?>), color-stop(100%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?>)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%); /* W3C */
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr="<?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?>", endColorstr="<?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?>",GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */}
```

However, only the first color show up (`$smof_data['color_scheme_one']`), and the second color is not showing up (`$smof_data['color_scheme_two']`).

Can you please tell me my mistake ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show where you are defining the variables? Besides, you can see the final result in the browser, if you see the source code to check what's wrong.

Comment: **Why is all your text bold?**

Comment: I just want to make it easy to read

Comment: allright. I've unbolded the text.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia ... I've checked the front end in the browser and still can't figure out the problem. So for example this code =
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%);

==> The color_scheme_two variable should be replaced by #22b6f4,But it didn't.(The hex color is choosen from the other page which will be called with the $smof_data function).

Comment: As soon as you start mixing PHP, CSS, JavaScript and HTML together then it's the time you start to get problems. If you isolate your code then you pretty much avoid all non-sense workarounds. Each language (except for HTML which is not a language) has it's own purpose and should be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

For php controlled CSS you should use a php stylesheet.

Head of html doc

`<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />`

PHP Stylesheet

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "#555555";
   $CDNURL = "http://cdn.blahblah.net";
?>

#header {
   background: url("<?php echo $CDNURL; ?>/images/header-bg.png") no-repeat;
}
a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}

...

ul#main-nav li a {
  color: <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}
```

PHP CSS stylesheet tutorial http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: Yes, I've done your suggestion above and it worked with the other css code.However, the problem I asked is about using multiple php command,for gradient background.

Here's more details = my css code is
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0a4999 0%, #22b6f4 100%);

I want to change the #0a4999 and #22b6f4 with php command. I've done this, but only the first php echo show up on the front end, the second echo is not showing up.
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_one']; ?> 0%, <?php echo $smof_data['color_scheme_two']; ?> 100%);

Where's the mistake ?

Comment: **AS I MENTIONED IN MY ANSWER** - if the echo is not showing up at all - there WAS NOT any `$smof_data['color_scheme_two'] = SOMETHING;` ...the code is otherwise ok - http://ideone.com/5PUH9f

Comment: You must ensure the variables are being set, and they are of correct format. var_dump the variable to the screen and read it. This will ensure you know what is being output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change just parts of your CSS which is in the `<head>` the best way is NOT to execute the non-dynamic CSS inside PHP, I would recommend this:

```
<?php 
//some php in here - setting $color_variable1 = something; and $color_variable2 = something;
?>
<head>
  <style>
    .someClass{
      color: #fff;
      /* background-color: <?php if($condition) echo "#FFF"; else echo "#000"; ?>; */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $color_variable1; ?> 0%, <?php echo $color_variable2; ?> 100%);
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
<?php 
//another php maybe?
?>
```

**EDIT:** If the second color from your "color array" is not showing up at all e.g. the output is something like `background: ;` - that just mean that there is nothing on that array index  - `empty($smof_data['color_scheme_two']); // would return true`

**Make sure that you have somewhere done:** `$smof_data['color_scheme_two'] = "someValue";`

**EDIT2:** from your comment it looks like you are trying to make this one:

`background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, <?php echo $color_variable1; ?> 0%, <?php echo $color_variable2; ?> 100%);`

Comment: Thank you for taking time answering my question.However, With "background-color", I can only use 1 color as the value. On this case, I use "background" which has multiple hex color as the value. So the problem I asked is about using multiple php command,for gradient background. Here's more details = my css code is => background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0a4999 0%, #22b6f4 100%); I want to change the #0a4999 and #22b6f4 with php command. what do you think ?

Comment: It was just an example of mixing CSS&PHP please dont take it literaly - please check the "**EDIT2:**"

Comment: yes, you are correct. I'm trying to make that code. however, the echo $color_variable2 is not showing up.

Comment: So it has to mean that it wasnt initialized anywhere :) could you provide the whole code - including the initialization of your $smof_data array fields?